# How to label images collaboratively?

Tags: object-detection

I am currently working on a project that involves building a model to detect a specific object within a set of images.

The first step we are taking so that model can be generated is, of course, labeling the object in the images we've got. The problem is, though, that we have too many images (approximately 17,000) and we are looking for a way to do the labeling in a collaborative manner as to reduce the workload.

So, is there any tool that would allow us to do that with relative ease? Online tools are out of the picture since we cannot upload the images to an external server due to data-sensitivity matters. We are looking to either perform the labeling locally and then join the results in some way or deploy a tool in an internal server so we can all access it and work on the images there.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/VoTT#labeling-an-image Does this help?

Comment: I will give it a deeper look and let you know, but an option to run it as a web application (which can then be accessed by multiple parts to work on the same labeling project) seems to be only available by uploading images to an external server, right? I will try to see if there's any way to deploy that web application on an internal server.

Comment: You can deploy it in your own workstation as well depending on the number of people accessing it simultaneously and the configuration of your computer. 8 GB RAM, 4 core CPU I think is good enough to host with 25 people accessing it simultaneously. More accurate and tighter bound stats you will have to research.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't look like VoTT is viable in that case, unless I am missing something. I was able to get the web version of VoTT up and running on my machine, but that version only allows the labeling of images that are either from Azure Blob Storage or Bing Image Search. There is no option to get the images from the local file system, that's only available on the desktop version.

Comment: What's the issue with desktop version then? You can distribute images and then combine the annotated after they are done. Or you can store them in a network file server then you can load them directly in the desktop version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225222/discussion-between-ranka47-and-matheus-correia).

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce the workload, you can try collaborate DL detection and hand label apps. However, the DL detection can be trusted mergely and you have to self verify every image. I used to use label image [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) to annotate for detection work.

For my work, I plan to auto-assign label every time a click the next image and I will only need to verify and correct it. I attach the prediction part of that detection inside this [part](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/blob/master/labelImg.py#L1327) of LabelImg code. You can try with others too.

For easier multi class label, I suggest you use YOLO or SSD or any multiple output detections with fast inference. It may need a little hard code to make it work in LabelImg but the result can be a little ease.

Comment: Yeah, we are going to use YOLO. I looked at the solution you provided, but LabelImg doesn't seem to have a web version that allows multiple people to work on the same labeling project.

Comment: U can separate data for people and each one use that configured python. Or you have to create a Django project with this app as backend

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.